# React Jest tests fails with react-dnd: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, react-dnd

Suffering from a weird error and currently can't get through. So When I run tests console throws:

```
/var/www/html/node_modules/react-dnd/dist/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export * from './core/index.js';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^


SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I Googled. People were discussing and saying module mappers should be added, so I added this code inside jest config:

```
'^react-dnd$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dnd/dist/cjs',
'^react-dnd-html5-backend$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-dnd-html5-backend/dist/cjs',
'^dnd-core$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/dnd-core/dist/cjs',
```

Another error thrown:

```
 Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^react-dnd$/": "react-dnd/dist/cjs"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }
```

If anyone has solved this with react-dnd please help me out! :))

Comment: Can you include the full `moduleNameMapper` section of your jest config? Are you using Babel? 
Some from [this issue](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/3443) got around this by ignoring DND  files from babel transformation  via `transformIgnorePatterns`

Comment: See the last answer here, that is your go to solution, please accept it if it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!react-dnd|core-dnd|@react-dnd|dnd-core|react-dnd-html5-backend)"
    ]
}
```

or, if your project uses it, to `jest.config.js`:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!react-dnd|core-dnd|@react-dnd|dnd-core|react-dnd-html5-backend)"
    ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not help, I doubt it ever did.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Add the common javascript libraries to your project
I'm using yarn

yarn add react-dnd-cjs

yarn add react-dnd-html5-backend-cjs

Then in your package.json add...

"jest": {
"moduleNameMapper": {
"react-dnd": "react-dnd-cjs",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "react-dnd-html5-backend-cjs",
"dnd-core": "dnd-core-cjs"
}

had some issues building in azure even though this worked locally so just downgrading to 15.1.2 fir now and that doesn't have this issue

Comment: Amazing, this solved it! I assume it makes sense since `react-dnd` dists no longer have any `cjs` folder and probably were moved to their respective packages. It's incredible to be solving issues like this 10 years into modern javascript, we have learned NOTHING